# Determining when a UIPageViewController scrolls past last page

Tags: ios, swift, uipageviewcontroller

I'm attempting to dismiss a UIPageViewController which is presented modally when the user scrolls past the last page. Is there a way to tell when this happens? 
viewControllerAfterViewController is called when the last view controller is shown.

Edit: I've also tried to add UISwipeGestureRecognizers but they are not being called.  I think this is because the UIPageViewController's gesture recognizer's disable them.

Answer (score 1):

`UIViewController:viewWillAppear:animated` will get called when the user swipes to that page.  So you could add a dummy last page, and dismiss the pageViewController when that gets called.

Answer (score 0):

You didn't indicate what language you're using so here it is in Objective-C

You should have your `viewControllerAfterViewController` method set up to look something like this:

```
- (UIViewController *)pageViewController:(UIPageViewController *)pageViewController viewControllerAfterViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController {

    NSUInteger index = [(CustomViewController *)viewController index];

    index++;

    if (index == 10) { // the number of controllers you have.
        return nil;
    }
    return [self viewControllerAtIndex:index]; // you view controller creation method.   
}
```

`viewControllerAfterViewController` is called whenever a user attempts to swipe through your pages. If the user tries to go beyond the last page, this method should return nil. When that happens, dismiss the `pageViewController`.

Comment: Thats not my question: once I am on the last page, how can I tell if the user attempts to scroll further?

Comment: In that case viewControllerAfterViewController should return nil. If its nil, dismiss your pageViewController

Comment: In my original post I said that viewControllerAfterViewController is called when the last view is shown, not when it is swiped.

Comment: It should also be called when the user tries to swipe past the last controller.  https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIPageViewControllerDataSourceProtocolRef/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/UIPageViewControllerDataSource/pageViewController:viewControllerAfterViewController:

Comment: Its not called; I just tested it again.  The function is called when a page is loaded to load the next one, not on the swipe.